# TestNg Assertions failure skip the test - data driven Iterator

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running a search with an iterator and asserting using TestNG `Assert.assertFail`.
I handle the code using `try{}catch{}` mechanism to ensure that the tests don't break if an assertion fails. But I find that the code breaks in case of assertion failure, I am looking for a way by which the WebDriver should search with the next record in the iterator list in case of failure. kindly help....

```
while (countryListiterator.hasNext()) {

            Thread.sleep(2500);

            countryListiteratorNextVAL = countryListiterator.next();

            searchResultPO toSearchpage = homeTosearch
                    .search(countryListiteratorNextVAL);

            // Do an Assertion here, if fails the test-ng class breaks without going to the next record.
                 Assert.assertFalse(boolean  condition)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the design, It would fail/break. You will have to reinvent assertion by following the link (http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/)